# How to implement ngGridEventScroll in ngGrid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have a ngGrid with large numbers of data. I want to apply scrolling to the grid. I found that ngGridEventScroll is the solution, but i didn't find any sample. Could anyone please help me on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well now i am able to implement ngGridEventScroll for my grid,

1. I have created a service to load the data.
2. I have injected the service into my grid directive.
3. Calling the function which load on ngGridEventScroll  event.

someting like this

gridScrollHelper is a service in which is injected in a directive for grid

```
angular.module("modulename").directive('directive name', ['gridScrollHelper',
unction (gridScrollHelper) {

    scope.$on('ngGridEventScroll', function () {
        gridScrollHelper.scroll(scope);
    });
}]);
```

Please refer https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Grid-Events